PHP openssl lib / ECDSA / How set random number for openssl_sign function?
How set (or get after signing) random number for function openssl_sign?
$pkEcPem = "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----302e0201010420...a00706052b8104000a-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----"
$pk = openssl_pkey_get_private($pkEcPem);
$signature = null;
openssl_sign($message, $signature, $pk, $algo);
openssl_free_key($pk);

Example of implementation in the PHP library
https://github.com/phpecc/phpecc/blob/master/src/Crypto/Signature/Signer.php#L36
Variant names of this value

random Key
random Number
random Point


The fact that k (the random number) must be generated explicitly is a peculiarity of the linked library. Depending on the value of k, the library controls in this way whether the non-deterministic ECDSA variant (arbitrary k) or the deterministic ECDSA variant (determination of k according to RFC6979) is used (see the ECDSA sample).

In most libraries, the generation of k takes place internally (and is not carried out by the user) and different methods or a flag are used to distinguish between the two variants (if the library offers both variants at all). AFAIK, openssl_sign() only supports non-deterministic ECDSA. For deterministic ECDSA you have to use a different library.
